# Assign value to variable in ff

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I am working with a ff dataset (final_faf_data) because of the size of my database. I am trying to create a new variable dpy which has only only one value (365) for all rows. When I try the following cmd (similar to what I would do in a dataframe)

```
final_faf_data$dpy <- 365
```

I get the following error

```
Error in `[[<-.ffdf`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 365) : assigned value must be ff
```

So my question is how do I assign it? I tried

```
vmode(final_faf_data$dpy, 365)
```

But it gives "NULL"

Any insights would be much appreciated.

TIA,
Krishnan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample data to reproduce your issue

`L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac)
final_faf_data <- as.ffdf(df1)`

Error messages given by the lines below are clear:

```
final_faf_data$dpy <- 365
final_faf_data$dpy <- as.ff(365)
```

Therefore, modify `365` accordingly:

```
final_faf_data$dpy <- as.ff(rep(365, times=nrow(final_faf_data)))`
```